# Directive for picture in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I recently discover directives in TeXstudio like `%!TEX root = ../main.tex`; this concept is fantastic.

I tried to find a directive saying the folder where picture should be upload. I mean, is there a directive able to say something like: `%!TEX picture folder = ../../picture` ?

Comment: `\graphicspath{{../../picture}{folder2}}`

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you know of a duplicate (I couldn't find a clear one), or do you want to answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't find a dupe too. But my comment above is a general one where as the OP may be expecting some thing like `%!TEX picture folder=...` kind of command which IIRC, does not exist for texstudio (there is no need for one IMO as there is `\graphicspath` or `TEXINPUTS`). So I am confused whether to write an answer or not!.

Comment: @HarishKumar I think you should answer. Saying "this is not possible as far as I know, but you can do this other thing instead" is also an answer. But it's up to you.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I cooked up an answer finally, hope that would do. :-)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

The `graphicx` package (which you should be loading anyway) offers `\graphicspath` command where you can provide a list of folders like `\graphicspath{{../../picture}{folder2}}`. LaTeX will search for images in these folders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{./img/}{./pictures/}}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{one}   %picture named one in directory img
    \includegraphics{two}   %picture named two in directory img
    \includegraphics{three} %picture named three in directory pictures
\end{document}
```

An advantage of this command is that it will work in any editor (not only texstudio), thanks to cfr for reminding. You can read on `graphicspath` in `grfguide` (`textdoc grfguide` from command prompt)

Hence the need for a command like `%!TEX picture folder=...` in texstudio doesn't arise and there is none to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: (+1) You might also add that a further advantage is that this will work regardless of editor.

Comment: Can't upvote again :(.